# MySQL: Can't Figure out how make this work

Tags: mysql

I Have THis MySQL store procedure, This store procedure should get `start` and `count` from outside and should somehow bind SQL depends on the `count` value. for example when the count value is `NULL` I would get the whole products list, otherwise, get by the limitation

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `products_get_list`(
IN start INT,
IN count INT
)
BEGIN
    CASE 
        WHEN count IS NOT NULL THEN
            (SELECT * from `products` LIMIT start OFFSET count)
        WHEN count IS NULL THEN
            (SELECT * from `products`)
    END;
END
```

Any Help will be apreciated. Thank you!

Comment: As an aside, note that LIMIT without ORDER BY is fairly meaningless

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I Figured out

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `products_get_list`(
IN vstart INT,
IN vcount INT
)
BEGIN

    IF vcount IS NOT NULL THEN 
        SELECT * from `products` LIMIT vstart, vcount;
    ELSE
        SELECT * from `products`;
    END IF;
    
END
```

Also here is the second way is this normal way to resolving this?

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `products_get_list`(
IN _start INT,
IN _count INT
)
BEGIN
    DECLARE _limit INT;
    SET _limit = (SELECT IFNULL(_count, (SELECT count(id) from `products`)));
      
    SELECT * from `products` LIMIT _start, _limit;
END
```

But if there is any other better way I will be happy to know.

Comment: Right, `CASE` expects an expression; it isn't a flow control structure. Also, don't confuse [`IF`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/if.html) with [`IF()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/flow-control-functions.html#function_if).

Comment: Thanks, @ÁlvaroGonzález will check the difference. And can you please have a look at the second way I need your opinion connected with the second one.